# Move (each) element to first-matched element

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I've been twisting my brain over this for a while now: I need to get a jQuery function to move each instance of `.THIS` after the first-following `.THAT`. I broke it down to this simple HTML example:

```
<table><tr>
    <td class="1a">1a</td>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="3a THIS">3a</td>
    <td class="4a">4a</td>
    <td class="5a THAT">5a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="1a THIS">1a</td>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="3a">3a</td>
    <td class="4a THAT">4a</td>
    <td class="5a">5a</td>
</tr></table>
```

And I figured this would work

```
var source = jQuery('.THIS');
var destination = jQuery(source).nextAll('.THAT');
jQuery(source).insertAfter(destination);
```

But whenever I try this, both sources (`.THIS`) get moved after the last instance of `.THAT`, like so:

```
<table><tr>
    <td class="1a">1a</td>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="4a">4a</td>
    <td class="5a THAT">5a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="3a">3a</td>
    <td class="4a THAT">4a</td>
    <td class="3a THIS">3a</td>
    <td class="1a THIS">1a</td>
    <td class="5a">5a</td>
</tr></table>
```

Instead of this:

```
<table><tr>
    <td class="1a">1a</td>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="4a">4a</td>
    <td class="5a THAT">5a</td>
    <td class="3a THIS">3a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="3a">3a</td>
    <td class="4a THAT">4a</td>
    <td class="1a THIS">1a</td>
    <td class="5a">5a</td>
</tr></table>
```

So how can I use jQuery to move each instance after the first other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tackle each `.THIS` individually, and place it after the *first* entry in `nextAll()`'s results.

```js
var source = jQuery('.THIS');

source.each(
  function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    $this.insertAfter( $this.nextAll('.THAT')[0] );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="1a">1a</td>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="3a THIS">3a</td>
    <td class="4a">4a</td>
    <td class="5a THAT">5a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="1a THIS">1a</td>
    <td class="2a">2a</td>
    <td class="3a">3a</td>
    <td class="4a THAT">4a</td>
    <td class="5a">5a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great, works like a charm! I figured I needed to use jQuery(this); somehow, but I stared blind at it. You're my hero of the day :D